# FTP virtual paths. How to know real Windows path?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, windows, ftp

I have shared hosting account on some hosting service provider. So, I can upload pics or something else through FTP. For instance, my ASP .NET binaries are in `/mysite.com/www/bin`. But how can I set logging to file in my app? I should use real paths for that purpose. I even try just write to current directory, but I can see this log file through FTP. It just writes to some tmp path as I guess, like '' which couldn't be accessed through FTP.
So how can I setup file path for logging?

---

This is how I try to write to current binaries directory:

```
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(String.Format("{0}{1}{2}", Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), "\", "log.txt"), true))
{
  sw.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString() + ": " + msg);
  sw.WriteLine("------------");
  sw.Flush();
  sw.Close();
}
```

It write to some long windows path, which I guess it uses for some temporary storing of binaries.

Comment: Some code would probably help.

Comment: Here you are. Please see post update.

Comment: Is this only on a web host (meaning *they* manage the IIS) or on a virtual server that you manager (meaning *you* manage the IIS)?

Comment: I don't administer the server. Based on your terms, they manage the IIS.

Comment: Then you're out of luck. They probably don't want their disk space used up by random web apps, and if they have a way to manage it then they should be the ones to tell you what to do.

Comment: @M.Babcock Just find out that you just invoke HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath to get absolute OS path to your account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it myself. You should use `HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath` for that.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your question is "I have FTP server running and serving content of "C:\myFTP\" how can I write log files (i.e. from ASP.Net application) to file available via FTP from the server?"

Answer - just write logs to that "C:\myFTP" location (or whatever location your local FTP server is configured to serve.

Comment: I don't have my own server. I just have shared hosting account.

Comment: Have you tried to ask hosting provider's support on where to write files in this case? It is unlikely anyone here will be able to provide more useful answer without knowing exact hosting provider/hosting setup/restrictions.

Comment: I'd like to know common, general path to get this location on any hosting provider.